# Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to localhost: Apache2 configuration in MacOsX (without MAMP)

Tags: php, apache

I have a machine with Linux and a nother one with MacOsX: the former for web development, the latter for iOS development. I just want to start using my MacBook for web development and stop to have two machines. I dont like virtual machines.

(PS. If I can, I'll like to not install any software like MAMP)

So, ... I've activated apache2, I've defined a VirtualHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin sensorario@gmail.com
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias senso.local.com
    DocumentRoot /Users/simonegentili/Development/Www
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    <Directory /Users/simonegentili/Development/Www>
            AllowOverride all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/localhost.error.log
    LogLevel notice
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/localhost.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And also this DocumentRoot:

```
DocumentRoot "/Users/simonegentili/Development/Www/"
```

But I see only a message like this:

```
Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to localhost
```

Comment: Is apache (httpd process) running? can you check and verify if it is running at default port (80) ?

Comment: Are u running the apache server that comes with osx through the web sharing option? Or did u brew install it and add a launchctrl script? If ur running it from the terminal are u sudo? Users typically cannot bind to port 80.